# Using C# FileStream as input to Regex.Match method

Tags: c#, regex, filestream

I am trying to write a program using C# in Visual Studio on Windows 10 and have found that the `Regex.Matches` method takes two strings one for the input and the other for the regex string to use. My input is a `FileStream` and this doesn't appear to convert to `string`. It is an array like structure.

How to use regular expressions upon a file stream? I have done some searching but have not come up with anything conclusive.

Comment: Regexes don't like endless data.

Comment: Are you able to just read the full contents of the file and match against that?

Answer (score 0):

Regex is intended for matching text patterns, not binary patterns. Is your file a text file? If so, use File.ReadAllText() instead of FileStream. If not, you'll need to explain your data and what you are trying to do so we can offer a better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no its a hex file; I cannot post it up as it contains sensitive data; is there any form of regex that can operate on a hex file stream?

Comment: @Myron: No. Regular expressions are specifically designed to operate on text. (But there's also no such thing as a *hex file*. Files are either text or binary. Please edit your question and make it clear what you're asking and what file type you're reading.)

Comment: @MyronGoldman we would need to know what format the file is actually in... post a small portion of it that doesn't contain sensitive data. If you mean its binary, then are you sure you don't want to deserialize it?

Comment: I can't really post any; however it is most certainly not a text file so therefore it must be binary.  I am taking a look at the following:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz(v=vs.110).aspx